# Explore promise value in Debug Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

While debugging node process in vscode, I can write arbitrary expression to be evaluated in the Debug Console. But I don't know how to get value if I write expression that returns Promise. It would be handy for example to explore what is in database calling the model function that returns promise.

I tried

`Format.all(context.engine).then(formats => console.log(formats))`

But still getting only Promise object back and not the value to be resolved.

Comment: Can you write block of code where you resolve promise?

Comment: can't you just put an `await` before the promise value to await it? At least, you can do that now in more recent node versions and browser versions.